# Inline two divs side by side - CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I am trying to place two divs of width 50% each but somehow its not appearing on same row, but if I do 49% it stacks in same row. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong with the code(more interested to know the cause than solution).

**CSS -**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.left-c {
  width: 50%;
  background: #3EF00C;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right-c {
  width: 50%;
  background: #2E4E6E;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML -**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-c">
        <p>LEFT ----- This is going to be some random text placed in a a left container inside the wrapper. I hope this text will suffice the requirement.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-c">
        <p>This is going to be some random text placed in a a right container inside the wrapper. I hope this text will suffice the requirement. ----- RIGHT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/no0chhty/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/no0chhty/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic issue with elements of type `inline-block`. Unfortunately, they take document whitespace into account, including blank characters. There are multiple solutions for this, but the one I tend to use involve setting their parent element to `font-size: 0` and then resetting the font size on the inline blocks to your desired value.

Read more about this here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Awesome, this theory is really helpful +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Add float:left; to the class "left-c"

```
.left-c {
          width: 50%;
          background: #3EF00C;
          display: inline-block;
      float:left;
        }
```

Please check out the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/no0chhty/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `display: inline-block`
to `display: table-cell`
for both sections like so:

```
.left-c {
  width: 50%;
  background: #3EF00C;
  display: table-cell;
}

.right-c {
  width: 50%;
  /* 49% works well */
  background: #2E4E6E;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ftss26ru/)

Answer (score 0):

replace this css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
   .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex
  }

  .left-c {
    width: 50%;
    background: #3EF00C;
  }

  .right-c {
    width: 50%;
    background: #2E4E6E;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi instead of inline block you can you float or flex like this:
link here https://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/r9s3z07e/

CSS

```
.left-c {
  background: #3ef00c none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-c"><p></p></div><!----><div class="right-c"><p></p></div>
</div>
```

**putting comment** between closing tag of left-c and opening tag of right-c will solve the issue.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/no0chhty/3/)